# Khinchin's constant bad estimate

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Inspired by `How to write down numbers having an infinity of decimals?` [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwqoAVMzgp4)

### Background

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant): for almost all real numbers \$x\$, coefficients \$a_i\$ of the continued fraction expansion of \$x\$ have a finite geometric mean that is independent of the value of \$x\$ and is known as `Khinchin's Constant`.

[Khinchin's Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KhinchinsConstant.html) can be calculated using the following method:

1. Using the \$n\$ first terms of the `simple continued fraction` of a real number ([For example  Pi](https://oeis.org/A001203)).
2. Compute their product
3. Apply the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ root on the absolute value of product calculated above

### What is a simple continued fraction

It can be expressed as:
$$x=[a_0; a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$$
Or
$$
x=a_0+
\cfrac{1}{a_1+
 \cfrac{1}{a_2+
  \cfrac{1}{\ddots{+
   \cfrac{1}{a_n}}}}}
$$

And can be calculated using the following:

1. Separate \$x\$ into its integer part \$a_n\$ and decimal part \$d\$

   - \$a_n = \lfloor x \rfloor\$
   - \$d = x - \lfloor x \rfloor\$
2. Repeat using the inverse of \$d\$ in place of \$x\$ while \$d\$ is not 0

It is a `simple` continued fraction because the numerator is always 1.

For negative numbers, the same rule applies, the first term of the sequence will be negative.

For example for \$π\$:
$$
π = [a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots] = [3; 7, 15, 1, 292, \dots]
$$

$$
π=3+\cfrac{1}{7+
     \cfrac{1}{15+
      \cfrac{1}{1+
       \cfrac{1}{292+
        \cdots}}}}
$$

And \$-π = [-4; 1, 6, 15, 1, 292, \dots]\$

### Challenge

Using the method used to approximate `Khinchin's Constant` described above:
Given a number of terms \$n\$ and a real number \$x\$, compute the geometric mean of the coefficients of the continued fraction expansion of \$x\$.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test cases:

| Terms to use | Real number | Expected Result | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) | 3 |  |
| 2 | [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) | 4.5825... |  |
| 3 | [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) | 6.8040... |  |
| 7 | [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) | 5.1179... |  |
| 7 | -[π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) | 5.2165... |  |
| 15 | [ℯ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) | 1.8156... |  |
| 15 | -[ℯ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) | 1.9164... |  |
| 20 | -[φ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) | 1.0717... |  |
| 20 | [φ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) | 1 |  |
| 100 | [φ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) | 1 | Optional, might not work because of consecutive floating point errors |

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: Can we work with floating-point numbers and accept some small inaccuracy derived from that?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure floating point numbers are all good as long as the 4 first decimals are correct for the test cases

Comment: Which invalidates my answer. \o/

Comment: @Arnauld it was looking correct to me?

Comment: No, [it returns `1.744...` for the last test case](https://tio.run/##bYy9DoIwFIX3PsVdTO6t8lMMMZEUJxIYTPoKBKFqSGuEdOTVKw4s2u2c7zs5z9a1U/d@vObI2FvvB@mNLJ0sUcs1mMuyOK7RROLgpEjQ7QTRWRAa4hxFYsirBiRc2/keq6Zg1Vaqgqn6q1DAHnLgHNI4J0ggKxjrrJns2Mej1Tjg@qcaoh@aBekxSE9BKnLC6v8hXcd1YJ1uwn8A) because of too many consecutive floating point errors and I can't think of any reasonable fix.

Comment: The 100 in the test case is arbitrary. If we can't submit answers in some languages in JS, I think I should reduce the numbers of terms to 30?

Comment: I think the problem with `phi` using floating-point numbers may be in defining the input, rather than in the computations. `phi` cannot be defined exactly as a floating-point value

Comment: FWIW, using [the same (ungolfed) algorithm in Python](https://tio.run/##XY/BCsMgEETv@Yq5FDQVqwmhUOjHBKqNh6iIFfr1dk1pCbnsMjNvWDa@8xL8WOvDWFjmBQq/dUDEHZq2DQkOziPN/mmYEvBb/iUiesoyK3yzSivhAlZwgm5eMvmVfON6sBZ5Xm0KK9Y5L3BrDCmj7@LiqMq0VDhjokm4khOnwiBVF1M7YpkWiI7zvx4Oejzo60HrScDseXqHTu8J9bPqBw) leads to the exact same results. (I think most if not all implementations of Python map floats to IEEE-754 / double precision, just like JS does.)

Comment: Almost any language designed to run on a real machine will have the same problem (unless it's a CAS like Mathematica) because they all use IEEE754 representation for real numbers. A possible fix is to simply allow FP errors without mentioning accuracy at all.

Comment: Is `x` guaranteed to be positive? If not, I suggest adding a test case with a negative numer

Comment: Being pedantic, the challenge isn’t to calculate Khinchin’s constant but rather the (related) geometric mean of the coefficients of the continued fraction expansion of \$x\$. According to Wikipedia, \$\phi\$ and \$e\$ are among the exceptions to the ‘almost all’ clause: the geometric means for these numbers do *not* converge to Khinchin’s constant. None of this changes the task as specified, but perhaps the wording could be clarified.

Comment: Thanks @Bubbler, I took your feedback in account and removed the accuracy criteria

Comment: @LuisMendo, good point, I added a negative test case

Comment: @Dingus, I rephrased it, I hope it is better?

Comment: Even for CAS systems it is literally *mathematically* impossible to take an arbitrary real number as input since there are more real numbers than there are finite strings.  Even Mathematica runs into the same precision issues that floating point solutions do, just less frequently.

Comment: I've VTCed this as unclear because I don't know what you mean by "simple continued fraction". Could you please expand on that, and add a worked example or 2?

Comment: Should we support rational inputs? They have a finite continuous fraction expansion, and some answers fail in that case

Comment: Also, and related to Shaggy's question: should we interpret that all coefficients in the expansion except the first must be non-negative? What is the expansion of `-pi`? I'm VTC'ing too until resolved

Comment: To add to Luis Mendo's comment, I believe that -pi has a very different continued fraction expansion from pi if we adhere to wikipedia's definition, so (7,-pi) should give a very different answer from (7,pi).

Comment: looking forward to it coming back, really fascinating puzzle

Comment: As a quick way to avoid the current difficulties with this challenge, I would suggest restricting to positive `x`, enforcing that all coefficients in the expansion be positive, and restricting `n` to be equal or less than the number of coefficients in the expansion, if the expansion is finite (which happens for rational `x`)

Comment: I reopened the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23903/97729) post with some updates to get some feedbacks. Let me know if it looks better and if it needs more changes :)

Comment: I'm still concerned about how precision is going to be handled.  Some of your inputs are transcendental numbers which sort of brings a lot of this stuff into question.  As stated before it's just not mathematically possible to take an entire real number as input so I really think this challenge should be clear in how precision is intended to work on both the input and the output.

Comment: Too hard for me, I'm giving up, thanks for your time and feedbacks! (looks like I can't delete it)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
^\¹Π↑¡§,o\%1⌊²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY27CUJREESrMRPcz9z99PIwFgwMxBYMxMQONDI3M70FWISNrFuFw4GBw8DsTsd91XaZ78/9e77Nx3yuD8uKv9fLfFUVGwepZoQjIxEIIYywUKgN02B2F1JK9gwabhImrAPoFqchRmjJkSRAOvW8QQtNZnVsmP6Q6pcf) for the last test case (or [try it here](https://tio.run/##vcutDQJREEbRanAkzP/M18sGvQkCQWgBQTB0AAqPw74CKGIbGbYKrjnqzufToXs/jc/3sVzu4zle2@O04eV2He/uVjZ2SLh6IaGiZSFhqqWScJIqYyQHFNB0Ji8hpMFsHZWyOIxCKoQKWClSK3E1YU6KxI7pD3X@AA) for n=7, number=pi).

```
     ¡          # Apply function repeatedly to first results, 
                # collecting second results into infinite list:
      §,     ²  #  combine pair of results of functions applied to arg 2:
            ⌊   #   floor
        o\%1    #   reciprocal of fractional part
    ↑           # Now take arg1 elements from list,
   Π            # calculate the product,
^               # and raise to the power of
 \¹             # reciprocal of arg1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.continued-fractions math.unicode`, 66 bytes

```
[ 1vector over [ dup next-approx ] times 1 head* Π abs nth-root ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBS8NAEIXv@RXv4ElIMYoICl6ll17EU@lh3UzMYjK7zs6WSsh/6S/qX4pbUqnFuX3z3jx40xirXqa31@Xq5REmRm8jPkmYOmzpqEX0Rlt0TklMN9PCeo5qWM@ojhPVZSM50GUVkb4SsaWTpUl8EoKQ6ncQxzpLiZ31NeGpKIYCea4GVAgO4y/dXtDdBT38J6aP86a6B/1JukFoj/5inNao5orwWxKsUaeQb3damhDE77CBuj4XqNCSqa9x2MO8R7C2pXiv2EwDxvlpz70JWEw/)

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes an integer signifying the number of terms to use and a real number and returns a real number. Assuming `3 3.141592653589793` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

| Snippet | Comment | Data stack (top on right) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1vector` | Make a vector out of the object on top of the data stack. This is how `next-approx` expects to take its input. | `3 V{ 3.141592653589793 }` |
| `over` | Put a copy of the object second from the top on top of the data stack. | `3 V{ 3.141592653589793 } 3` |
| `[ dup next-approx ]` | Push a quotation to the data stack for `times` to use later. | `3 V{ 3.141592653589793 } 3 [ dup next-approx ]` |
| `times` | Take an integer and a quotation and call the quotation that many times. In this case, equivalent to `dup next-approx dup next-approx dup next-approx` |  |
|  | Inside the quotation now... | `3 V{ 3.141592653589793 }` |
| `dup` | Copy the top data stack object | `3 V{ 3.141592653589793 } V{ 3.141592653589793 }` |
| `next-approx` | Add the next term in the continued fraction to our vector. `next-approx` has stack effect `( seq -- )` so we made a copy so we don't lose it | `3 V{ 3 7.062513305931052 }` |
| `dup next-approx` | Iteration 2 | `3 V{ 3 7 15.9965944066841 }` |
| `dup next-approx` | Iteration 3 | `3 V{ 3 7 15 1.003417231015 }` |
| `1 head*` | Remove last element | `3 V{ 3 7 15 }` |
| `Π` | Take the product | `3 315` |
| `abs` | Take the absolute value | `3 315` |
| `nth-root` | Take the nth root of a number. In this case, take the cube root of 315 | `6.804092115953367` |

Answer (score 3):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <strike>42</strike> 38 bytes

```
N@1##&@@ContinuedFraction[#2,#]^(1/#)&
```

Corrected formatting and size reduced by @theorist.

Inputting n=100 and variable as Pi we get the output as

```
2.69405
```

You can save 2 bytes by removing N@ but this will give an exact expression and not numeric.

The code also passes all the tests giving the exact value for each number except for -Pi for which it returns a complex number. However the magnitude of this complex number is exactly the same as that given in the expected value.

Comment: For this site, you'll want to format your code as a program that can take the arguments as input, e.g.: `N@1##&@@ContinuedFraction[#2,#]^(1/#)&` (38 bytes).   This would be implemented as: `N@1##&@@ContinuedFraction[#2,#]^(1/#)&@@{n,x}`, e.g., `N@1##&@@ContinuedFraction[#2,#]^(1/#)&@@{100,Pi}`

Comment: You can remove the whitespace

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 47 bytes

Expects `(n)(real)`.

```javascript
n=>v=>(g=n=>n?~~v*g(n-1,v=1/(v%1)):1)(n)**(1/n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzNCsIwEITveYq9CLvR/mylCJbUU6E9CHmFUm1VSiK25NhXj/HgRXub@eZjHq1rp@51f86RsZer75U3qnSqxEGFYE7L4uSAJuKdU5yg2zDRkQkNSYmcGPK6AQXndr7FuilE9S1VIXT9mZBhCzlICWmcEySQFUJ01kx2vMajHbDH8Kcboh@ardL9Kj2sUs4Jq/@HNMh1sP0b)

Note: With 40+ terms, the last test case will diverge from 1 because of cumulated floating point errors.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
->n,l,r=1{n=n.abs;l.times{r*=n.to_i**(1.0/l);n=1/n%=1};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3RCoIwGIXve4puArd@535DBGXdddkTyIgJWcJcMhcY02dfol0G5xz4vptj3/UnNCLEZwMarEBvhGGqHkrNXNvdB2/pItzr1lIaIeOJJqURmJiDwLm0c6gQUjhBDsiXrN3mt1yyTvV@Gqd@31QxMmUfMMp5t2K0CQK5XMVVuWdRXACzjaOMUs6yI5JkeeF/JKZchi8)